# Relocate symfony config directory

Tags: debian, symbolic-link, configuration

I have a new symfony project. In order to satisfy Debian's FHS I want to put the project's `config/` directory under `/etc` and create a symbolic link pointing from the normal `config/` location to the directory in `/etc`.

I have tried this but it does not work. I get errors from `ProjectConfiguration.class.php` complaining about not being able to find `sfCoreAutoload.class.php`.

```
require_once dirname(__FILE__).'/../lib/vendor/symfony/lib/autoload/sfCoreAutoload.class.php';
```

This makes sense since the original line no longer points at the correct location.

So I changed that line to an absolute path

```
require_once '/usr/share/myproject/lib/vendor/symfony/lib/autoload/sfCoreAutoload.class.php';
```

But now I get errors like

```
Uncaught exception 'InvalidArgumentException' with message 'The application "client" does not exist.'
```

Is there a robust way to relocate the `config/` directory of a symfony project? (I realize that there are good reasons not to do this, and I wouldn't if I did not have to, so please keep that in mind.)

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll find a better answer if you ask on Stack overflow.

I'm a symfony user, and I don't really get what you're trying to do.

First, you must (much more easy to maintain) create a symfony directory with all symfony component. You create symbolic link in your vendor.

If you've created a new project, then create a symbolic link in vendor to your symfony directory.

exemple : 
\etc\home\Project_Symfony\Symfony\ (the symfony directory with all component)
\etc\home\Project_Symfony\Project_1\ (your project folder)
\etc\home\Project_Symfony\Project_2\ (your project folder)

In you Project_1 & Project_2 create a symbolic link in the vendor directory.

From what I understand with your errors, you must recreate the link from your new project to symfony. Go look here to find help : http://www.symfony-project.org/jobeet/1_4/Doctrine/en/01